# See what the preprocessor is doing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there anyway to see what you code looks like after the preprocessor has done all the substitutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For gcc just use the `-E` switch

```
gcc -E
```

> -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.
>   The output is in the form of 
>   preprocessed source code, which is
>   sent to the standard output.

Comment: For MSVS users, see this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719234/see-what-the-preprocessor-is-doing

Answer (score 7):

That depends on your compiler.  With `gcc`, you would use:

```
gcc -E source.c
```

Comment: thanks you, for the fast and accurate responce, i should havce mention i was ussing gcc.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note about system headers (eg `<stdio.h>`): they are a pain when preprocessed.

`gcc -E -nostdinc file.c` or `cpp -nostdinc file.c` will not include expansion of system headers.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [`gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)`-E`, you can run [`cpp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) on your file.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse C++ IDE (CDT) has Macro Exploration control, which can be used for:

- Obtaining final macro expansion
- Looking through expansion process step-by-step

This is called [Macro Exploration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn60) control.